# Increase Max Header Size for Owin Hosting

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am running a Service Fabric WebAPI application that makes use of OWIN hosting.

I have run into an issue where we are getting a 400 response: `HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long`

Is there any way to increase the supported request header size? The request has a large jwt token in the Authentication header (20kb)?  I don' see a property in the `HttpConfiguration` properties

Comment: How long is the longest header?

Comment: i think about 14 kb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to do it programatically. Ended up setting reg keys to increase the max header size.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` 
`MaxRequestBytes` and `MaxFieldLength`